# Is there a way to change toggles?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, customization

Is there a way to change the toggles in Lollipop? I'd like to remove and add some.

Comment: Device needs to be rooted and Xposed framework installed to change them, unless you're using Cyanogen OS, then it would be easy to change some of them. Use [Gravitybox LP](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.lollipop.gravitybox).

Comment: This is reportedly a feature that's coming in M :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't edit the toggles in the stock ROM, but I've heard [Power Toggles](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.painless.pc&hl=en) works pretty well. I'm pretty sure that CM allows you to edit the toggles if you are rooted.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your device there may be the option to change the available toggles in settings or even in your notification pull-down.
Samsung devices (some) have this feature. [image: The icon in the top right corner is the option to change which titles are shown]

Comment: My device is rooted. So I have to install Xposed Framework?

Comment: That depends on your device. If those options aren't available to you, or to want more than to simply reorganize the toggles, then yes, xposed will benefit you.